(Windows) Can I differentiate between an admin user and a regular user using cmd as admin?
There is a very large pool of Windows developers who, even when your documentation specifically says not to, insist on running everything in an administrator command prompt. In a tool I maintain, I would like it to either warn or refuse to run if the tool is ran from an administrator prompt but I do not want to block running this tool on single user/passwordless Windows VMs (such as most CI/CD providers) where you're automatically admin no matter what.
Is it possible differentiate between the two?

Detecting an elevated split token - note that the original blog post was about detecting administrator, and detecting split tokens is the wrong way to do that. But detecting split tokens is what you are looking for! If user has administrator permission + token is split, then "Dude, don't run this elevated."

Sorry for the slow response. Yes, that's perfect! Someone escalating gets a TokenElevationTypeFull, someone who can escalate but hasn't gets TokenElevationTypeLimited and everyone else (full admin or no admin or UAC off) gets TokenElevationTypeDefault  so just testing for TokenElevationTypeFull is all I needed. It took me a while to convince myself that there wouldn't be edge cases but it's now published and downloaded by 100,000 Windows users without anyone moaning at me so all looks good....

Python implementation here (plus a UNIX equivalent) in case anyone wants it.
